How to pass bytes (base64) instead of string (utf-8) to Gemini using requests package in Python?
I would like to use the streamGenerateContent method to pass an image/pdf/some other file to Gemini and have it answer a question about a file. The file would be local and not stored on Google CloudStorage.
Currently, in my Python notebook, I am doing the following:

Reading in the contents of the file,
Encoding them to base64 (which looks like b'<string>' in Python)
Decoding to utf-8 ('<string>' in Python)

I am then storing this (along with the text prompt) in a JSON dictionary which I am passing to the Gemini model via an HTTP put request. This approach works fine. However, if I wanted to pass base64 (b'<string>') and essentially skip step 3 above, how would I be able to do this?
Looking at the part of the above documentation which discusses blob (the contents of the file being passed to the model), it says: "If possible send as text rather than raw bytes." This seems to imply that you can still send in base64, even if it's not the recommended approach. Here is a code example to illustrate what I mean:
import base64
import requests

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    file = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode('utf-8') # HOW CAN I SKIP THE DECODING STEP?

url     = … # LINK TO streamGenerateContent METHOD WITH GEMINI EXPERIMENTAL MODEL
headers = … # BEARER TOKEN FOR AUTHORIZATION
data    = { …
            "text": "Extract the written instructions from this image.", # TEXT PROMPT
            "inlineData": {
                "mimeType": "image/png", # OR "application/pdf" OR ANY OTHER FILE TYPE
                "data": file # HERE THIS IS A STRING, BUT WHAT IF IT'S IN BASE64?
            },
          }

requests.put(url=url, json=data, headers=headers)

In this example, if I remove the .decode('utf-8'), I get an error saying that the bytes object is not JSON serializable. I also tried the alternative approach of using the data parameter in the requests.put (data=json.dumps(file) instead of json=data), which ultimately gives me a “400 Error: Invalid payload” in the response. Another possibility that I've seen is to use mimeType: application/octet-stream, but that doesn’t seem to be listed as a supported type in the documentation above.
Should I be using something other than JSON for this type of request if I would like my data to be in base64? Is what I'm describing even possible? Any advice on this issue would be appreciated.

Can't skip the step.  JSON needs str type not bytes type.

@KJ makes sense, so my question is how would I be able to transfer content in base64 format if not through JSON?
